# Posting long content throws "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue"

Tags: c#, string, image, base64, botframework

I am using BotFramework to draw strings on a PNG image. Then I convert it to a base64 string from a byte array in memory. I post the base64 string to a service and get the correct response. Everything works fine but, I get the "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" message after the process.

```
case 5:
{
    try
    {
        ...
        graphics.DrawString(text, fonti, brush, drawRect, stringFormat);

        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            // I've tried changing this line to String or StringBuilder but
            // nothing changed              
            IMAGE = $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(m.ToArray())}"; 

            m.Close();
        }
    }
    catch { await context.PostAsync("ERR1"); }

    string json = null;
    try
    {
        string FormStuff = string.Format($"somecontent");
        StringContent content = new StringContent(
                                      FormStuff,
                                      Encoding.UTF8,
                                      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        string url = string.Format("http://www.example.com/");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        json = (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToString();
    }
    catch { await context.PostAsync("ERR2"); }
    ...
}

break;
```

`IMAGE` variable is a string.

Whenever I remove or change **Convert.ToBase64String()** the problem is gone but then I can't use the service as I want and the process is broken.

Only problem here is the exception thrown and shown to the end user.

> Sorry, my bot code is having an issue

**EDIT:** I found out that if the content in my post request is too long, I get the error message. I've tried using `FormUrlEncodedContent` but it throws this:

> Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

How could I post it in another way?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Side note: It may be that you're only working with PNG images anyway, but since you're definitely claiming that the output is a PNG, why not use `ImageFormat.Png` rather than taking *whatever* `image.RawFormat` returns.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever didn't fix the problem

Comment: That's why I prefixed it with "side note" and posted it as a comment, *not* an answer. It wasn't going to fix the problem (or at least looked <1% likely to) but is something you ought to consider for cleaning up the code once your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what service you are calling or do not have all the values for your parameters to test this with. but this is too long for a comment.

Try this instead of `.ToArray()`  try something like

```
 var image = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("FileName"));
```

You also may want to try this setting this to a variable outside of the string you are forming `IMAGE` with.  Something like this I have had success with in the past, but again I do not know what your service is doing or expecting.

```
   var image = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(
        "FileName"));

    image64 = "data:image/png;base64," + image;
```